# If $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous then $\left\lvert\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx-\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}f \left(\frac kn\right)\right\rvert<\frac{M}{2n}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous on $[0,1]$, so that $|f(x)-f(y)|<M|x-y|$ for all $x,y\in[0,1]$; prove $$\left\lvert\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx-\frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac k n\right)\right\rvert<\frac{M}{2n}$$

I get RHS $\frac{M}{2n^2}$ instead.  Book seems to give that answer then confusingly states $\frac{M}{2n}$ at very end.  Just want to confirm which is correct.

EDIT:  Nevermind its $\frac{M}{2n}$.  question is from Intro to Calculus and Analysis Vol 1 By Courant, S2.3.3

Comment: For $f(x)=x$, the LHS is exactly $\frac1{2n}$ hence the RHS cannot be of order $\frac1{n^2}$.

Comment: @Did omg forgot to do a summation at the very end.  Thanks

Comment: Because then the integral is $\frac12$ and the sum is $\frac12n(n+1)\frac1n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx-\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k/n)\right|&=\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n}(f(x)-f(k/n))dx\right|\\
&< M\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n}|x-k/n|dx\\
&=M\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n}(k/n-x)dx\\
&=M\left(-\int_{0}^{1}xdx+\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\right)\\
&=M\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\cdot\dfrac{n^{2}+n}{2}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{M}{2n}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Rather note that, for every $k$, $$\int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n}(k/n-x)dx=\int_0^{1/n}xdx=\left.\tfrac12x^2\right|_0^{1/n}=\cdots$$ and proceed.